# java HttpURLConnection.addRequestProperty "Authorization" doesn't work

Tags: java, http-headers, authorization, token, httpurlconnection

I'm building a java 8 console program to get data from a remote web service.
That service needs an authorization token in the form:
"Authorization: Bearer <my token>".

My connection code:

```
    final URL url = new URL("https://<service url>");
    final HttpURLConnection cnn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    cnn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    cnn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
    Map<String, List<String>> props =  cnn.getRequestProperties();
    int size = props.size(); // size is always 0
    cnn.connect();
    int status = cnn.getResponseCode(); // status is always 404
```

I found "Authorization" is a disallowed request property so I run this code with JVM property
`-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true`.
Running my code I can find `cnn.getRequestProperties()` is always empty as my property was discarded and not used and, maybe a consequence of that, connection status is 404 (Forbidden).

I cannot ask to service-supplier to change the way everybody can authorize himself to its service.
Anybody know the way to get "Authorization" property accepted ?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Haye you tried adding cnn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: I tried and props.size()==1 (but I set 2 properties).

Comment: I found 404-status was a fault of mine. my token wasn't well-created. sorry!
Anyway getRequestProperties() don't return all set properties yet